# grafana: remove legend caption prefix

Tags: grafana

I'm using `6.2.9` version of grafana.

Currently, this is my legend format: `{{class}} - {{method}}` and I'm getting this legend captions:

[image]

I'd like to remove `cat.gencat.catsalut.hes.mpi.api.providers.` prefix from `{{class}}`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

You can try it like this, edit the panel, click `Transform` and `add transformation` and rename the query result by regex.

[image]

Hope this helps!